# Asking the user to input numbers and multiplying them together

Tags: python

I've attempted the following, but I don't get my expected output.

```py
def main():
    while True:
        numbers = list(map(int(input("Enter a number: ").split())))
        answer2 = input("Continue? (yes/no) ")
        if answer2 == "no":
            break
        numbers.append(answer)
    print(multiply(numbers.append(answer)))

def multiply(numbers):
    total = 1
    for x in numbers:
        total = total * x
    return total 
main()
```

Comment: please format your code, and include your example input and result as text.  "can't get this code to work" implies you're seeing either error or unexpected behavior, and we need to see it to , to most efficiently answer this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are quite many errors in this code. First of all the `answer` variable is not set anywhere, but that may be a leftover. Then secondly the casting from string to int to map to list is for sure something that doesn't make any sense. Also keep in mind that the `numbers` variable is reassigned in every loop iteration, so even if you continue, you'd lose the previously entered data. Fixed code:

```
def main():
    numbers = []
    while True:
        answer = int(input("Enter a number: "))
        numbers.append(answer)
        answer2 = input("Continue? (yes/no) ")
        if answer2 == "no":
            break
    print(multiply(numbers))


def multiply(numbers):
    total = 1
    for x in numbers:
        total = total * x
    return total

main()
```

Output:

```
Enter a number: 1
Continue? (yes/no) yes
Enter a number: 5
Continue? (yes/no) yes
Enter a number: 3
Continue? (yes/no) no
15
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! After reading through your answer i realize i have no idea what i was trying to do with the list and map functions. I now understand what i did wrong. Thanks once again!

Comment: @SohaibA.Siddiqui Welcome! If the answer helped you, you can accept it as the correct one.